# Strange warning gcc

Tags: gcc, warnings

Can someone explain this warning message ?

```
rx@bet~/Scrivania/rx_fine$:gcc -c -Wall proxy_invio.c
proxy_invio.c: In function ‘main’:
proxy_invio.c:1028:26: warning: variable ‘len2’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
```

This is the content of the proxy_invio.c file :

```
#define GETMHTTP "GET mhttp://"

main(){
    int len2;
    //blablabla

    len2=strlen(GETMHTTP);
    //blablabla
}
```

@EDIT: it was just an error created by a copy-paste misused. I was not so stupid to not understand the meaning of the warning message, but so stupid to not see forward.

Comment: Well, you set it ... and never used it. Where's the confusion? Typing the error into google brings up a number of pages, one of which shows that's new in gcc 4.6; https://wiki.edubuntu.org/GCC4.6

Answer (score 0):

You have set the variable, but you never used it later (after `len2=strlen(GETMHTTP);`).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple : you set the variable to some value, but you never use it afterward.

I thinks it's pretty safe to say that you can simply delete these two statements from your code. Or maybe you were planing on using `len2` somewhere but you forgot.